# Join of indexed ids over 3 tables unexpectedly slow

Tags: postgresql, performance, jpa

I have three tables that build a hierarchy:

- Table `customer` with primary key `id`
- Table `portfolio` with primary key `id` and foreign key `fk_customer` (indexed)
- Table `position` with primary key `id` and foreign key `fk_portfolio` (indexed)

Customers have portfolios (but some do not), and portfolios have positions (but some do not).

I have a view which basically selects this hierarchy, which is usually queried with in-clauses on customer-ids, portfolio-ids or position-ids. The **performance on selects using this view is surprisingly bad, and takes over a second where I'd rather expect execution times under 10ms.**

To analyze the performance, I isolated and simplified the query as follows:

```
SELECT bp.id, ptf.id, pos.id FROM customer bp
left outer join portfolio ptf on ptf.fk_customer = bp.id
left outer join position pos on pos.fk_portfolio = ptf.id
WHERE ptf.id IN (1, 2)
OR pos.id IN (3, 4)
```

In a concrete setup (**70k customers, 100k portfolios, 600k positions**), this query takes almost a second (for about 10 rows returned). I rebuilt this setup (same data, same number of records) on Oracle and Postgres, both showing the same performance problems.
When I change the view slightly (`WHERE pos.fk_portfolio IN (1, 2)`), the execution time is about 0.1ms, but then the portfolios without positions are not returned.

Execution plan on Postgres:

```
Gather  (cost=22125.87..27689.07 rows=13 width=24) (actual time=703.717..782.415 rows=9 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Hash Left Join  (cost=21125.87..26687.77 rows=5 width=24) (actual time=700.739..751.123 rows=3 loops=3)
        Hash Cond: (ptf.id = pos.fk_portfolio)
        Filter: ((ptf.id = ANY ('{1,2}'::bigint[])) OR (pos.id = ANY ('{3,4}'::bigint[])))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 202202
        ->  Parallel Hash Left Join  (cost=3057.84..5195.48 rows=42990 width=16) (actual time=70.319..171.940 rows=39930 loops=3)
              Hash Cond: (bp.id = ptf.fk_customer)
              ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using sys_c0011416 on customer bp  (cost=0.29..1440.43 rows=29642 width=8) (actual time=0.026..20.169 rows=23714 loops=3)
                    Heap Fetches: 0
              ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=2298.91..2298.91 rows=60691 width=16) (actual time=69.626..69.627 rows=34392 loops=3)
                    Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 5920kB
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on portfolio ptf  (cost=0.00..2298.91 rows=60691 width=16) (actual time=0.027..38.559 rows=34392 loops=3)
        ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=13796.90..13796.90 rows=245690 width=16) (actual time=415.120..415.121 rows=196552 loops=3)
              Buckets: 131072  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 2816kB
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on "position" pos  (cost=0.00..13796.90 rows=245690 width=16) (actual time=0.009..222.681 rows=196552 loops=3)
Planning Time: 1.280 ms
Execution Time: 782.808 ms
```

Disabling the sequence scans (`set enable_seqscan = false`) didn't help either.
I also

- made sure the indexes (on the foreign key constraints) exist and are active
- updated statistics and compacted the tables (VACUUM ANALYZE on all 3 tables)
- reindexed the tables (REINDEX on all 3 tables)

I found **other ways to express the query** (with two separate selects and id filtering, then union both) which show excellent performance, but **none that would allow me to create a view** where I can filter by customer/portfolio/position ids afterwards.
Example with union (execution time <1ms):

```
(select bp.id, ptf.id, pos.id from customer bp
    left outer join portfolio ptf on ptf.fk_customer = bp.id
    left outer join position pos on pos.fk_portfolio = ptf.id
    where ptf.id IN (1, 2))
UNION
(select bp.id, ptf.id, pos.id from customer bp
    left outer join portfolio ptf on ptf.fk_customer = bp.id
    left outer join position pos on pos.fk_portfolio = ptf.id
    where pos.id IN (3, 4))
```

I'm at my wits' end - I would have expected the query to be very fast, given that:

- it does not really fetch any data (only the primary keys)
- filters by primary keys only, and
- joins by indexed foreign key columns.

I hope that any of you fellows can shed some insight on why the performance is so bad (on Postgres and Oracle), and suggestions on how I can fix that.

**EDIT:** 
I'm querying the data over JPA (Java Persistence API), which does NOT support unions. I would however be able to use the union as part of the view definition, as I only need to pass the criteria (in clauses) over JPA.

Comment: Regarding returning the customers with no matching portfolios, you have to include these in the where clause, i.e. add `OR ptf.id IS NULL` and `OR pos.id IS NULL`

Comment: @Adder in the case where I have restrictions on portfolios and/or positions, I specifically want to exclude customers without portfolios and positions, as they match neither the porfolio nor id criteria.

Comment: The condition `pos.id IN (3, 4)` turns the outer join to `position` back into an inner join - is that really what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will certainly need the variant with `UNION`, because the `OR` cannot perform well.

The problem is that PostgreSQL cannot deduce from the `IN` lists that it can convert the outer joins into inner joins.

Try to either write inner joins:

```
(select bp.id, ptf.id, pos.id from customer bp
    join portfolio ptf on ptf.fk_customer = bp.id
    left outer join position pos on pos.fk_portfolio = ptf.id
    where ptf.id IN (1, 2))
UNION
(select bp.id, ptf.id, pos.id from customer bp
    join portfolio ptf on ptf.fk_customer = bp.id
    join position pos on pos.fk_portfolio = ptf.id
    where pos.id IN (3, 4));
```

or try adding a condition that may give PostgreSQL a clue:

```
(select bp.id, ptf.id, pos.id from customer bp
    left outer join portfolio ptf on ptf.fk_customer = bp.id
    left outer join position pos on pos.fk_portfolio = ptf.id
    where ptf.id IN (1, 2))
      and ptf.id IS NOT NULL
UNION
(select bp.id, ptf.id, pos.id from customer bp
    left outer join portfolio ptf on ptf.fk_customer = bp.id
    left outer join position pos on pos.fk_portfolio = ptf.id
    where pos.id IN (3, 4)
      and pos.id IS NOT NULL);
```

I am not sure if the second query will do the trick.

Comment: This solution is not usable as a view (which I could query with different filters of portfolio or position ids), and unfortunately I cannot use unions when querying, as I'm using JPA (unless I fall back to native queries).

Comment: I would then recommend that you do *not* use a view. It is a common misconception to create a "world view" of all the data and treat is as a denormalized table in queries. You cannot use views that way efficiently; as you see, the conditions matter a lot. You can, however, create a view for each type of query as a way of an interface that hides the actual table definitions. As to the restriction imposed by your choice of ORM: either use a more flexible ORM, or use a native query.

Comment: I ended up using the view, but querying it twice (once filtering by position ids, once filtering by portfolio ids). In the end it's like using a union (which would require me to implement it as native query with JPA as union is not directly supported), only this way I get full JPA support, at the overhead of executing two (simple) queries (which however can be done in parallel) and then combining the results. Accepted you answer, thanks.